# Filter a View with a dropdown list in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to filter a list view using a dropdown as a filter.

My controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? TradeExerciseNumber)
{
    var TradeExerciseEntries = new TradeExerciseController().GetAll();
    ViewBag.TradeExerciseEntries = new SelectList(TradeExerciseEntries, "TradeExerciseID", "TradeExerciseNumber");

    if (TradeExerciseNumber != null)
    {
        return View(await db.TradesModels.Where(x => x.TradeExerciseId == TradeExerciseNumber).ToListAsync());
    }

    return View(await db.TradesModels.ToListAsync());
}
```

And my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <p>
            Find by Exercise Number: @Html.DropDownList("TradeExerciseEntries", -how do I pass value to TradeExerciseNumber in my controller to let it render pls- )
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </p>
    }
```

Now, how do I pass the dropdownlist value to `TradeExerciseNumber` in my controller to let it render please? Thank you very much.

Best regards

Comment: There's a pretty detailed example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I did in my view and it worked:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Trades")){   
<p>
    Find by Exercise Number: @Html.DropDownList("TradeExerciseNumber", ViewBag.TradeExerciseEntries as SelectList, null, new { onchange = "submit();" })
</p>
}
```

I hope it helps. Thanks